# Why is Jest --watch executing repeat test runs slower on one machine than another?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, typescript, jestjs

I've got a simple React example app written in TypeScript.

There is the most basic Jest/ts-jest configuration and two simple tests.

```
"jest": {
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
  },
  "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$",
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "ts",
    "tsx",
    "js",
    "jsx",
    "json",
    "node"
  ]
}
```

On my Mac, the initial `jest --watch` run takes just over 2 seconds. When I hit enter, it takes another 2 seconds or so to re-run the tests.

On my friend's Linux machine the initial run takes a couple of seconds. Then when he hits enter, the tests run in milliseconds.

Jest seems to be loading everything in from scratch on my machine for every run, but making good use of caching on the other machine.

The jest cache directory contains files. I emptied it and re-ran the tests and found new cache files were created, but the problem remains.

Could this be cache related? What might cause the tests to be so much slower to run subsequent times on the Mac?

Comment: A new project without ts-jest works as expected so I'm looking in that direction.

Comment: Re-runs are lightning fast as expected on the Mac if I downgrade Jest to 22.4.4 and ts-jest to 22.4.2. Looks like a 23.x problem, but only on my Mac so far.